# Why does my browser still show the loading icon after I clicked the button?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does my browser still show the loading icon after I clicked the button?

jsfiddle.net/QuwUF/1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printName(name){
        var message= document.write("hi " + name);
        return message;
    }
</script>


<form>
    <input type="button" onclick='printName("scotty")' />

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "still rendering"?

Comment: What do you mean? If you click the button, the message is written to the page.

Comment: My browser shows the loading icon after I clicked the button.

Comment: Go back to the beginning. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It might be possible that it doesn't like document.write. Try using innerHTML or similar instead.

Comment: I'm trying to learn javascript

Comment: I'm not trying to access any html within the web page, so I don't think innerHTML is a good soln.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you posted. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/QuwUF/1/

Comment: jayp, is that your puppy, he looks so cute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (implicitly — by calling `document.write()` on a closed document) open a new document, but after you write to it, you never call `document.close()` so it never finishes "loading".

Comment: Ah, I see this occur all the time by newb developers.  So is your suggestion to still use innerHTML?

Comment: Still? I am not jayp. Any suggestion to use `innerHTML` or otherwise would have to be based on knowing what problem was being solved in the first place. Adding a call to `document.close()` would inflict the minimum of changes in how the current code you have works.

Comment: If the goal is to learn JS, then I'd suggest using [a decent guide](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum) rather then one that started with document.write (which should almost never be used in practise).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I don't intend on using document.write.  I just felt it was a good way to test some output with javascript.

"The entire HTML page will be overwritten if document.write() is used inside a function, or after the page is loaded."